# Powering 5 V and 3.7 V devices from the same power source

Tags: power-supply, power, voltage-regulator, ldo

I need to power a Raspberry Pi (5 V, drawing around 0.8 A) and a device (3.7 V, drawing around 70 mA) from the same power supply. The project implies only one power source.

What solution would you recommend to power those two units that will give you the smoother Vouts?

- Using a 5.1 V wallwart and with it powering the Raspberry and using a 3.7 V LDO regulator with a capacitor after that for powering the second device.
- Using a new 9 V or 12 V wallwart and regulating 5 V with a L7805 for the Raspberry and LM317 for powering the second device.
- Other solutions and why?

More info:

The 3.7 V device is intended to be powered from a 3.7 V battery.
It receives a wireless signal -> output through a 3.5 mm jack audio cable.

When this one is powered from its battery, it has much less ground noise than when it's powered from the LDO.

More more info:

The [LDO](https://www.mouser.it/ProductDetail/628-812C37AY-G) I chose for the test is the wrong one because it has a minimum Vin of 5.7 V and a maximum current out of 50 mA and, although it is working, is certainly the reason for the ripple that I measure at the output.

I need your advice to understand if you would just choose another (correct) LDO or if you would choose another option.

Comment: It would depend how much the Raspberry Pi consumes current. Can you add that to your question. Also what device wants 3.7V at 70mA? How clean supply it requires then? If it has also 3.7V IO connections to Raspberry Pi, how have you prevented overvoltage from destroying RPi GPIO pins?

Comment: What LDO are you using?

Comment: How are you measuring 'dirtiness' and 'unstableness' and what are your goals for these specs?

Comment: Which Raspberry Pi?

Comment: LDO requires  capacitor in the output. Follow the datasheet. Wrong capacitor may cause output oscillation.

Comment: The dumbest solution would be to drop some voltage with a few series diodes. 5V-0.6V-0.6V = 3.8V, close enough - 3.7V device will probably work even with 4.2V - after all, 3.7V li-ion batteries have 4.2V when fully charged. Maybe dummy load resistor after diodes with ~1ma constant current load (4.7k resistor to gnd will do) would be a good idea to keep diodes biased - more stable voltage. It's not the best solution. It's pretty cheap and dirty. But it's very simple, and not (much) less efficient than LDO

Comment: RPi in this case is a 3b+ but why is that important if they are all powered at 5V? I haven't measured its current consumption yet but I believe should be max 0.8A.
The LDO I'm using is this https://www.mouser.it/ProductDetail/628-812C37AY-G
but was a wrong choice because it doesn't provide enough current and despite is "working", it requires minimum 5.7V input from the DS.  
 'dirtiness' and 'unstableness' are not engineering terms that refer to ripples measures with an oscilloscope.  
Mine was a dumb and hasty choice, therefore I'm looking for advices
Will edit the question

Comment: Just a question abou 3.7V: what are the tolerances on that?  Is it possible the device works on 3.3V which you can get from the Pi? (It seems it might be able to do [70mA](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/104825/what-are-the-max-current-rating-for-3-3v-and-5v-rail-of-the-rpi-4b))

Answer (score 1):

I would probably just use an LDO. The power losses will be 5-3.7V=1.3V and 1.3V*0.07A= ~90mW. The output is 20mv to 70mV of ripple so if you are measuring more then maybe a better LDO would work. It might also be your ground, make sure your ground is very low resistance/inductance (and also measure ripple from a grounding point near the LDO when measuring ripple).

Another option might be a DC DC converter
https://www.digikey.com/en/products/detail/recom-power/R-78S3-6-0-1/7932585

Comment: It is  90mW power dissipation

Comment: I guess the LDO is a good option and I will find another one because as for the edit in the question, I choose a wrong one and that should be the reason for my dissatisfaction.
Basically, the doubt and question show up since I can't find many 3.7 V Voltage regulators around... If not many are sold,  I ask myself why, and if people have better solutions for this.

Comment: I also bought a SMD one https://www.mouser.it/ProductDetail/595-TLV70237DBVR
but is so small that I can't even use it for a test.
Even though it looks interesting, I believe the DC DC linked is not going to work out since has output = 3.6 V. and i found no 3.7 to 4V similar converters

Comment: A single rectifier diode (e.g. 1N4001 and friends) has a drop of roughly 0.6 volts, so two (plus a smoothing capacitor) would provide sufficient voltage drop from 5V to power a 3.7V device; if it is designed to work from a 3.7V battery, it can't be too fussy about the precise voltage.